# Switching between two JavaFX stages

Tags: java, javafx

Basically, I made a function which switches between stages (see the `Switch` class below).

The way I call it is seen in the Controller below. I wanted to ask if this code  (in the `Switch` class) is good practice or not.

**Login class:**

```java
public class Login extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Login.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Login");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**FXML:**

```xml
<BorderPane
        fx:controller="client.controller.LoginController"
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <center>
        <GridPane alignment="CENTER" hgap="10" vgap="8">
            <Button fx:id="registerButton" onAction="#goToRegister"
                    text="Register" defaultButton="true"
                    GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
        </GridPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

**Controller:**

```java
public class LoginController {
    public Button registerButton;

    public void goToRegister(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Switcher.switchWindow((Stage)registerButton.getScene().getWindow(), new Temp());
    }
}
```

**Switch class:**

```java
public static void switchWindow(Stage window, Application app) {
    try {
        app.start(window);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Temp Class:**

```java
public class Temp extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/temp.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Temp");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```